# What is StackExchange? Is Ask Ubuntu officially related to Ubuntu or Canonical?

Tags: support, stackexchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Ask Ubuntu “official” Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5444/is-ask-ubuntu-official-ubuntu)

What is stackexchange? is Ask Ubuntu officially related to Ubuntu/canonical?
How do i subscribe for a question that I have not asked?