# Is AskUbuntu owned or operated by Cannonical?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is StackExchange? Is AskUbuntu officially related to Ubuntu or Canonical?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/434/what-is-stackexchange-is-askubuntu-officially-related-to-ubuntu-or-canonical)

I have a "simple" question that I can't find the answer to anywhere online. Is AskUbuntu owned or operated by Cannonical? If not, who ownes it?

Comment: Mabe cause you are writing it wrong? ;) http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/434/what-is-stackexchange-is-askubuntu-officially-related-to-ubuntu-or-canonical