# Is Ask Ubuntu "official" Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

Meaning, is Canonical directly involved?  I see a few Canonical employees here (hi Jorge!), was just curious whether Canonical itself actually runs or supports Ask Ubuntu, or if it's purely "community" only.

Comment: Related: [Is Ask Ubuntu sponsored by Canonical?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19689)

Answer (score 23):

## Not directly.

Ask Ubuntu is and always will be a community run website on the Stack Exchange network. From what I've gathered, Stack Exchange and Canonical have entered a trademark agreement to use the "Ubuntu" name in the URL, to my knowledge nothing else exists in that agreement that mandates Canonical having *direct* involvement in the site. To some extent we're much like how the Ubuntu Forums are run, in the community does all the management. Moderators (here) are elected by the community members and for the most part we govern ourselves and follow the community guidelines that Canonical has set forth for the Ubuntu Project as a whole

Comment: Has it changed at all since it is linked from the Ubuntu installer and ubuntu.com?

Comment: This hasn't changed in the years since. Stack Exchange still runs Ask Ubuntu and Canonical does little to no interference with it's operatoin.

Answer (score 21):

I first heard about AskUbuntu via the images displayed during installation of 11.10, which (seems to me) is a pretty official endorsement.

Answer (score 20):

Canonical gave permission for Stack Exchange to use the Ubuntu trademark and logo for Ask Ubuntu. A Canonical employee also assisted in the site's new design to help meet the [Ubuntu Brand Guidlines](http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/ubuntu-brand-guidelines/).

Beyond that Canonical has made no public announcements relating to Ask Ubuntu. (So we must assume that the site is not officially endorsed by or related to Canonical).

(Note: There are Canonical employees that are members of the Ask Ubuntu community.)

Comment: Note that now their top bar includes us and their help pages and install recommend us.

Comment: @Braiam the company's [called Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) now.