# Is Ask Ubuntu vulnerable to Heartbleed OpenSSL problem?

Tags: support

Did the Ubuntu Single Sign On (SSO) ever vulnerable to [hreatbleed](http://heartbleed.com/), also known as CVE-2014-0160? If so, has it been patched? Should we change our passwords?

If not, it may be a good idea to post the information somewhere in the Ubuntu login site.

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu Single SignOn the OpenID provider? How is related to SE?

Comment: @Braiam I am sorry. I may be showing my ignorance here. I mainly use the Single SignOn to log into Ask Ubuntu. If this question is irrelevant I will be happy to delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask Ubuntu and the Ubuntu Single Sign On and two different things.

Ask Ubuntu is [owned and hosted](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7704/who-owns-ask-ubuntu) by [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/). While the Single Sign On(SSO), is owned by [Canonical](http://www.canonical.com/).

Being the creators of Ubuntu, I can be fairly certain Canonical are running Ubuntu Servers. And most likely using the OpenSSL library.

Again, I can be confident that they had patched and fixed the bug. But, if you are in doubt, it's never a bad idea to change your password.

P.S. Since you are using the SSO to sign in to Ask Ubuntu, your password is never shared with Ask Ubuntu (nor any other site whatsoever).